# How to add textures on top of textures?

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to create some sushi.

I've got this but I don't understand the UVWrapping as I need to almost decal some ingredients onto the rice texture.

[image]

As you can see, I went to edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) then selected the top and bottom of the sushi... I added a texture in that texture tab on the right, and then selected that texture from the UV editor... The rice appeared and I positioned the circles accordingly.

I then hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire sushi roll and then de-selected the top and bottom... In the UV editor, I then applied my sushi wrap texture.

Now what? How do I go and apply a texture of sushi ingredients on top of this roll?

[image]

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is... but at the top I see it says Blender render rather than Cycles... If you know what to do, I'd love to give you £10 to just show me how to create this sushi, then i'll know how it works in the future.. Skype screen share or something? I've been struggling for 6 hours now... doh

Comment: Jimmy there's lots of good tutorials on YouTube, look for Sardi Pax and Andrew Price. After following some of these you will pick it up much quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding a material, add two textures. The texture(s) lower on the list will be applied over the previous texture(s):

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting that outcome... any ideas (see OP picture)... Ignore the fact the sushi picture image isn't alpha.. I've enabled that, just forgot to when taking the screenshot

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Try putting them the other way. The list is in reverse order, bottom textures are really on top.

Comment: No difference whatsoever?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 huh.. Could you upload the .blend?

Comment: Ahhh, I went to Render mode and it then appears... In texture mode it wasn't showing the application of textures!

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Yes, texture mode only displays the active face textures. To see the combined textures outside of render mode, enable *GLSL* in *3D view > Properties panel > Shading*. [screenshot](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/76001)